# C++ Arrays & pointers

Tags: c++, c

can anyone help me with the following inequalities for arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRD(a) printf("%d", (a))
#define NL printf("\n")

int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4};

int main ()
{
  int i;
  int*p;

  for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    PRD(a[i]);
  NL;

  for (p=&a[0]; p<=&a[4]; p++)
    PRD(*p);
  NL;

  for (p=&a[0]; i=0; p+i<=a+4; i++)
    PRD(p[i]);
  NL;

  for (p=a, i=0; p+i<=a+4; p++, i++)
    PRD(*(p+i));
  NL;
```

Basically I dont understand the 4 loops, please kindly help to explain to me!

Comment: No wonder, I program in C++ for the last 15 years and I don't understand them either.

Comment: And as such, you should be able to get a good grasp on these by reading the first few chapters of any decent C++ programming book.

Comment: they are actually pointers and arrays, but i dont understand the conditions in the for loops, could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: @H2CO3 You mean a decent C book. A decent C++ book would shift the discussion of raw pointers and arrays towards the end.

Comment: @n.m. An ideal C++ book doesn't even mention raw arrays! C'mon, we're implementing a kernel in C++, let's use some `std::vector`s in a performance-critical tight loop! Yay!

Comment: 4th Loop increments p by by 1 i addes 2 to that address.. but adding i on it will add +2 on top of it. Means p+2+i

Comment: @H2CO3 Writing performance-critical tight loops in kernels is fine but it's not what you normally start with.

Comment: Yes, you can traverse an array in several ways using a pointer, you can imitate an array-pointer, use its address, & address arithmetic

Comment: `4 loops` ?  all 4 ? or  4th?

Comment: @H2CO3: Er, `std::array`? Besides, if you need to allocate dynamic memory in a performance-critical tight loop in a kernel, I sure as hell would use `std::vector`.

Comment: @DeadMG I was trying to demonstrate a case where you preferably don't have to do dynamic allocation.

Comment: @DeadMG - default dynamic allocation is often not available in such contexts and trying to use it will result in a kernel crash.  The vector class would require a special allocator/deleter, as would the objects contained. It could get messy..

Comment: I disagree on the off-topic flag. If you see the comment by Javier he is specifically asking for help on understanding how pointer arithmetic should be interpreted. This is a somewhat obscure feature of C and not really discussed in detail in most textbooks.

Answer (score 2):

A detail here, the "inequalities" you're asking about are about pointers, not arrays. Think of comparing memory locations, and the following will be easier to follow.

- First one should be pretty straightforward: print each element of the array in order (`a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc.)
- In number 2, `p` is the address of element `0` of `a`. `p++` increases that address to be address of the next element in the array.The termination condition can be read as "`p` is less or equal the address of element number 4 of the array". To put some values and make this concrete: imagine `&a[0]` is `200`, as a consequence `&a[4]` is `216`, as `p` is incremented it becomes `204, 208, 212, 216`, and finally `220`.
  When it becomes `220` the condition becomes false, and the loop ends.
- Number 3's left side is similar but instead of increasing `p` it adds `i` to `p`. Note that thanks to the magic of pointer arithmetic `p + 1` is actually `p + i*(sizeof(*p))`. The sequence is exactly the same as in case 2. BTW, initialization should be `p = &a[0]`, `i=0;` (note the comma before the `i`). For the right side `(a+4)`, the plain a means the address of the first element of a (this is the C equivalency between pointers and arrays, `a` topic full of subtleties and pain). `a + 4` is thus equivalent to `&a[4]`.
- Number 4 is there to mess with your head. The information above should be enough to translate the initialization and condition; but having both `i++` and `p++` means you will be advancing 2 elements each iteration.

The use of the preprocessor here is likely obscuring what gets called, try expanding manually to follow up more easily. and PRD should be adding a space after each number for easier reading.